# convert dataURL from variable into image

Tags: jquery, image, variables, todataurl

I'm trying to convert a dataURL to a png from a global variable (local storage).

I store it like this:

```
var image = signaturePad.toDataURL("image/png");
member.questions.signature = image
```

Now I need to display it in a table as a thumbnail. I've used this storage for purely storing text up until now. I'm baffled at how to convert the `dataURL` to an image.

This is what I've tried (I'm very new to code - apologies):

```
$('#your-signature').html(member.questions.signature);
```

But it just returns the dataURL - how do I reformat it please? Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You need to create an `Image` element and assign your `dataUrl` as it's `src` property. Then just place that image wherever you want using jQuery's [.html](http://api.jquery.com/html/) function.

So in your case, code should look something similar to:

```
var imageEl = new Image;
imageEl.src = member.questions.signature; 
$('#your-signature').html(imageEl);
```

And here is a sample code to play around:

```js
var signaturePad = new SignaturePad($("#myCanvas").get(0));

$("#showAsImage").click(function() {
  // Get DataURL
  var dataUrl = signaturePad.toDataURL("image/png");
  
  // Create image
  var image = new Image;
  image.src = dataUrl;
  // Add image element to wrapper
  $("#imageWrapper").html(image);
});
```

```css
canvas {
  border: 1px solid grey;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/signature_pad@2.3.2/dist/signature_pad.min.js"></script>

<canvas id="myCanvas" width="400" height="200"></canvas>
<br />
<button type="button" id="showAsImage">Show as image</button>

<div id="imageWrapper"></div>
```